# Set image of disable state for custom toggle in android

Tags: android, custom-controls, togglebutton

I make a custom toggle button in android, checked state and unchecked state are work fine with two image, now i want set disable image for disable state of toggle button. How i do that? Thanks!

This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/record_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/record_on" />
</selector>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you provide some code? What is your exact problem?

Comment: I want set image for disable state, how i do?

Comment: please update your question instead posting code in comments

Answer (score 6):

Make these changes in your `selector`

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/record_off" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/record_on" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/record_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
```

I am using this: `@drawable/record_disabled` merely as an example. You can have your own name for the `drawable` which you will have to create just like you must have done with the ON and OFF buttons. ;-)

*Note that I have added an `android:state_enabled="true"` attribute to all the items.*

The simplest thing you can do in such cases, is go to the location where you have your SDK placed. Then choose the platform you are building for. Go to the `data\res\drawable` folder and look at how Google does it.

Since you are customizing a `Toggle button`, search for this: `btn_toggle_holo_dark` or `btn_toggle_holo_light` in the **drawable** folder.

Comment: @DuHuynh: glad to have helped.

Comment: your note was really helpful! should be accepted as the correct answer